# Problema deserializando JSON con Newtonsoft con valores nulos

Tags: c#, newtonsoft

Estoy usando Newtonsoft en un proyecto en .net para deserializar un json así:

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<mi_tipo_objeto>(responseBody)` ("mi_tipo_objeto" es el objeto al que quiero deserializarlo)

Se deserializa correctamente pero los valores nulos en una propiedad string, en lugar de trasladarse como un valor *null*, se trasladan con el texto "(null)".

En el archivo JSON la propiedad se devuelve como *null*;

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente no hay error. El IDE muestra los valores nulos como "(null)" pero internamente es un valor nulo.